# Make attributes in a javascript constructor mandatory

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to write a class in javascript and make my constructor attributes mandatory. I'd like to know if this approach is ok, and if its not, why... Suggestions of how can I do that are welcome.

```
class Father {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
    this.validate = function () {
      if (!this.name) throw new Error('name not defined') 
      return 'constructor is ok' // this is just an example
    }
    this.validate()
  }
}

const jon = new Father()
```

Comment: Yes. why not? have you face any problem in validate?

Comment: Why don't let typescript take care of this

Comment: @krbalaji no, it does the job. But I've seen nobody using this approach.

Comment: @PabloRecalde, the stack in my company is just using vanila javascript.

Comment: This is not the right approach if you want to make the constructor param's `mandatory` because you are able to construct the object without any params.

Comment: Instead you should call the `validate` method from within the constructor, so you don't need to call it explicitly after constructing the object.

Comment: @TheAlpha …or not use any separate `validate` method at all, and just place the parameter validation logic right inside the constructor.

Comment: @TheAlpha yes, the ideia is bring this functions from a validator function, so I can use the same class to diferent objects, each one with their own specific validations.

Comment: @Bergi, it's possible but I like to keep my concerns separate, in small chunks of code and validation logic could grow if params grows but anyways, it's just a preference tho.

Comment: @TheAlpha It should be made a static method or a helper function though, not an instance method initialised in the constructor.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit for this type of question

Comment: @Bergi, I would like something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/heera/1roLcvdf/1/), a property/method in the prototype. Static method will introduce unnecessary complexity. Through `this`, the instance could be accessed to retrieve the properties for validation and practically, each instance will have it's own properties to validate.